# Complex merging between rows when sharing values with other groups in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Hello everyone I have a dataframe such as ::

```
  Families Species   Event      Groups
1  A,B,C,D     SP1 4,5,6,1 G1,G2,G3,G4
2    A,A,C     SP2   4,4,2       G1,G4
3        B     SP2       5          G1
4        A     SP3       2          G8
5        C     SP3       1          G9
```

and the idea is that I would like to merge rows by `Species` when :

- at least one element of `Families`,`Event` and `Groups` is shared by another `Species`.

So for instance we see for `SP2` `row2`  that :

- in `Families` **A** is also present in the `Families` of `SP1` (A,B,C,D)
- in `Event` **4** is also present in the `Event` of `SP1` (4,5,6,1)
- in Groups **G1** and **G4** are also present in the `Groups` of `SP1` (G1,G2,G3,G4)

AND

for `SP2` `row3`  that :

- in `Families` **B** is also present in the `Families` of `SP1` (A,B,C,D)
- in `Event` **5** is also present in the `Event` of `SP1` (4,5,6,1)
- in Groups **G1** is also present in the `Groups` of `SP1` (G1,G2,G3,G4)

then I can merge the `rows` and `row3` since they both share values with the `row1` of `SP1`.

so here is the **expected output**:

```
  Families Species   Event      Groups
1  A,B,C,D     SP1 4,5,6,1 G1,G2,G3,G4
2  A,A,C,B SP2,SP2 4,4,2,5    G1,G4,G1
3        A     SP3       2          G8
4        C     SP3       1          G9
```

If someone has an idea it would be amazing, thank you very much for your help and time.

**Here are the data :**

```
    structure(list(Families = structure(c(3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 5L), .Label = c("A", 
    "A,A,C", "A,B,C,D", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), Species = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("SP1", "SP2", "SP3"), class = "factor"), 
        Event = structure(c(4L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("1", 
        "2", "4,4,2", "4,5,6,1", "5"), class = "factor"), Groups = structure(c(2L, 
        3L, 1L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("G1", "G1,G2,G3,G4", "G1,G4", 
        "G8", "G9"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -5L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is an attempt, using data.table (but if you look a it, it's pretty possbile to do it without data.table, it's just that data.table is now my mother tongue) :

```
dt <-  structure(list(Families = structure(c(3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 5L), .Label = c("A", 
                                                                             "A,A,C", "A,B,C,D", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), Species = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                                                                                                     2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("SP1", "SP2", "SP3"), class = "factor"), 
                      Event = structure(c(4L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("1", 
                                                                          "2", "4,4,2", "4,5,6,1", "5"), class = "factor"), Groups = structure(c(2L, 
                                                                                                                                                 3L, 1L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("G1", "G1,G2,G3,G4", "G1,G4", 
                                                                                                                                                                             "G8", "G9"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  -5L))
library(data.table)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
setDT(dt)
library(stringr)

dt[, Families := as.character(Families)]
dt[, Event := as.character(Event)]
dt[, Groups := as.character(Groups)]
dt[, n := row.names(.SD) ]

dt2 <- merge(dt, 
      dt, 
      by = "Species")[n.x >= n.y]

dt2[, testFamilies := length(intersect(unlist(strsplit(Families.x, ",")), unlist(strsplit(Families.y, ",")))) > 0, by = 1:nrow(dt2)]
dt2[, testEvents := length(intersect(unlist(strsplit(Event.x, ",")), unlist(strsplit(Event.y, ",")))) > 0, by = 1:nrow(dt2)]
dt2[, testGroups := length(intersect(unlist(strsplit(Groups.x, ",")), unlist(strsplit(Groups.y, ",")))) > 0, by = 1:nrow(dt2)]

dt2[, Families := paste0(unique(unlist(strsplit(paste(Families.x, Families.y, sep = ","), ","))), collapse = ","), by = 1:nrow(dt2)]
dt2[, Event := paste0(unique(unlist(strsplit(paste(Event.x, Event.y, sep = ","), ","))), collapse = ","), by = 1:nrow(dt2)]
dt2[, Groups := paste0(unique(unlist(strsplit(paste(Groups.x, Groups.y, sep = ","), ","))), collapse = ","), by = 1:nrow(dt2)]

dt2[(testFamilies == TRUE | testGroups == TRUE | testEvents == TRUE)
    & !n.x %in% dt2[(testFamilies == TRUE | testGroups == TRUE | testEvents == TRUE) & n.x != n.y, n.y]
    & !n.y %in% dt2[(testFamilies == TRUE | testGroups == TRUE | testEvents == TRUE) & n.x != n.y, n.x], 
                     .(Species, Families, Event, Groups)]
```

Comment: Hello, thanks but I tried your code and I do not get the expected result, dt2 has no merged row betwen row2 and 3...

Comment: I don't understand .. In your exemple families for row 2 and 3 are "A, A, C" and "B" .. son I thougth they should not merge .. Oh .. ok, I missed the 'at least one of ..' I will edit my answer to match your goal ..

Comment: In SP2 row2 the ```Familly A``` is in ```SP2 row1``` & In ```SP2 row3``` the ```Familly B``` is in ```SP2 row1```  as well, so I merge  the two ```SP2 row2```  and ```row3```into the same row. See in the exemple I explained it better with more details. Ok I saw you just saw that point ahah thank you.

Comment: And there is also a little error somewhere in my code .. I'm looking at it ..

Comment: Thanks but again it does no look like the expected output... The row 1 as been removed and there is no merge betwen row2 and row3 as expected... You can see what is the exact expect output in the post if you want to refer it

Comment: Ok, I think you can work it out from my proposal, it's just a matter of concatening .. I've no time to go further for now, but if you don't achieve it by yourself I'll be happy to help later ..

Comment: Tahnk you very much for you time and implication !!! it works now :-)

Comment: Hello, do you have an idea in order to add a groupby ? I mean let's say I have a New_col and I do not whant to merge rows between different New_col values ?

Comment: Hello, sorry for that, but  I think it's better if you send a new question, with a new reproductible code (and if possible your attemps ...) (this is a good practice in order to prevent a question to turn into a full job ..)